How to style my FlatButton in Python Arcade
def create_click(self):
    button_style = {
        "font_name": ["Kenney Pixel", "Arial", "Kenney Bold"],
        "font_size": 20,
        "font_color": arcade.color.RED,
        "border_width": 2,
        "border_color": arcade.color.BLACK,
        "bg_color": arcade.color.BLUE,  # Hintergrundfarbe des Buttons
        "bg_color_pressed": arcade.color.LIGHT_BLUE,  # Farbe beim Drücken
        "border_color_pressed": arcade.color.BLACK,  # Randfarbe beim Drücken
        "font_color_pressed": arcade.color.WHITE  # Schriftfarbe beim Drücken
    }

    for i in range(0,4):
        start_button = arcade.gui.UIFlatButton(text="HIT",x= 125, y=680 - (i * 150), width=190, height=100, style=button_style)
        self.v_box.add(start_button)
        start_button.on_click = self.on_click_start

        self.manager.add(start_button)

Have came up with this function to create a clickable button. The Button works but I wanna style the bg_color and font_name. If I write it directly into the UIFlatButton nothin happens. I searched the arcade website and it suggested to use the style method which isn't working for me because I always get an error that "font_name = style.get(..." is noneType which I can't understand.
Tried to put the button_style elsewhere in my code but still doesn't change anything

You can configure button style the following way:
import arcade
import arcade.gui
import arcade.gui.widgets.layout
import arcade.gui.widgets.buttons
from arcade.gui import UIFlatButton


class MyView(arcade.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = arcade.gui.UIManager()
        red_style = {
            'normal': UIFlatButton.UIStyle(
                font_size=20,
                font_name=('calibri', 'arial'),
                font_color=arcade.color.RED,
                bg=arcade.color.BLUE,
                border=arcade.color.BLUE,
                border_width=2,
            ),
            'hover': UIFlatButton.UIStyle(
                font_size=20,
                font_name=('calibri', 'arial'),
                font_color=arcade.color.GREEN,
                bg=arcade.color.YELLOW,
                border=arcade.color.BLUE,
                border_width=2,
            ),
            'press': UIFlatButton.UIStyle(
                font_size=20,
                font_name=('calibri', 'arial'),
                font_color=arcade.color.RED,
                bg=arcade.color.WHITE,
                border=arcade.color.BLACK,
                border_width=2,
            ),
            'disabled': UIFlatButton.UIStyle(
                font_size=20,
                font_name=('calibri', 'arial'),
                font_color=arcade.color.RED,
                bg=arcade.color.BLUE,
                border=arcade.color.BLUE,
                border_width=2,
            )
        }

        self.v_box = arcade.gui.widgets.layout.UIBoxLayout(space_between=20)
        demo_button = arcade.gui.widgets.buttons.UIFlatButton(text='Button', width=200, style=red_style)
        self.v_box.add(demo_button)
        ui_anchor_layout = arcade.gui.widgets.layout.UIAnchorLayout()
        ui_anchor_layout.add(child=self.v_box, anchor_x='center_x', anchor_y='center_y')
        self.ui.add(ui_anchor_layout)

    def on_show_view(self):
        self.window.background_color = arcade.color.DARK_BLUE_GRAY
        self.ui.enable()

    def on_hide_view(self):
        self.ui.disable()

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        self.ui.draw()


window = arcade.Window()
window.show_view(MyView())
window.run()

Result:


font_name = style.get("font_name", UIFlatButton.UIStyle.font_name)
^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
Im always getting this error above, i don`t know if my code structure is trash but somehow it looks like I did everything necessary similar to our code

It's hard to tell what's going on without seeing your whole code.
